# Creating a report for a custom object using a filter based on a field from a standard object

Tags: reporting, community, joined-reports, custom-report-type

I have an object [database] called trainee that is linked to Leads via email address,

I want to create a report for the trainee database that includes a filter from Leads,

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the relation ship between lead and trainee ?
I mean lookup or Master detail.
I you have any of those relation then you can use lead fields as filters.

Thanks
Anil.B

Comment: I don't have those two,